# Get a warning when primitive type autoconversion in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, bit-manipulation, java-7

I'm doing an application which uses bit-wise operators in Java. The issue I have can be seen in this code:

```
// Downcasting
int i1 = 0x000000FF;
short s1 = (short) i1; // s1 = 0x00FF
byte b1 = (byte) s1; // b1 = 0xFF

// Upcasting
short s2 = b1; // s2 = 0xFFFF
int i2 = s2; // i2 = 0xFFFFFFFF
```

As you can see, because of the signed basic types in Java I get sign-extension when upcasting. Actually I can solve that problem, but I need some way to get a warning when doing those autoupcasting.

As an additional information, I'm using Eclipse Kepler and Java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible with default compiler implementation. You need to implement this by your own and create a compiler to add such kind of check.

Comment: It looks like it's worst the solution than the problem.

Comment: @Reignerok Unfortunately, this is the only solution I know. I would accept your comment (of being *worst* solution) only when you provide a better answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "worse". I meant that it's better for me just having the problem than solving it.